# Last value at least n seconds from resampling cut-off

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following DF:

```
import pandas

mydata = pandas.DataFrame({'TRADE_PRICE': {pandas.Timestamp('2016-07-12 10:52:58.850899935'): 9.23,
  pandas.Timestamp('2016-07-12 10:55:13.832099915'): 9.23,
  pandas.Timestamp('2016-07-12 11:09:17.775099993'): 9.22,
  pandas.Timestamp('2016-07-12 11:09:25.811100006'): 9.22,
  pandas.Timestamp('2016-07-12 11:09:26.020699978'): 9.22,
  pandas.Timestamp('2016-07-12 11:09:27.408600092'): 9.22,
  pandas.Timestamp('2016-07-12 11:11:48.448199987'): 9.22,
  pandas.Timestamp('2016-07-12 11:11:58.801599979'): 9.21,
  pandas.Timestamp('2016-07-12 11:11:58.810499907'): 9.21,
  pandas.Timestamp('2016-07-12 11:11:59.049000025'): 9.21}})
```

Now,

```
mydata.resample('1Min',label = 'right', closed = 'right').last()
```

Gives me the last trade before the end of the resampling period.

What I need tho is the last trade that is at least 5 seconds away from the end of the resampling period.

Basically, I want a sort of last() that would ignore all trades happening closer than 5 sec to the end of the resampling period.

So I would expect to get something like:

```
                     TRADE_PRICE
2016-07-12 10:53:00          NaN
2016-07-12 10:54:00          NaN
2016-07-12 10:55:00          NaN
2016-07-12 10:56:00         9.23
2016-07-12 10:57:00          NaN
2016-07-12 10:58:00          NaN
2016-07-12 10:59:00          NaN
2016-07-12 11:00:00          NaN
2016-07-12 11:01:00          NaN
2016-07-12 11:02:00          NaN
2016-07-12 11:03:00          NaN
2016-07-12 11:04:00          NaN
2016-07-12 11:05:00          NaN
2016-07-12 11:06:00          NaN
2016-07-12 11:07:00          NaN
2016-07-12 11:08:00          NaN
2016-07-12 11:09:00          NaN
2016-07-12 11:10:00         9.22
2016-07-12 11:11:00          NaN
2016-07-12 11:12:00         9.22
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first filter out any records that are more than 55 seconds into their minute, then continue on as you were.

```
mydata_ = mydata[mydata.index.second <= 55]

mydata_.resample('1Min',label = 'right', closed = 'right').last()
```

returning:

```
                    TRADE_PRICE
2016-07-12 10:56:00 9.23
2016-07-12 10:57:00 NaN
2016-07-12 10:58:00 NaN
2016-07-12 10:59:00 NaN
2016-07-12 11:00:00 NaN
2016-07-12 11:01:00 NaN
2016-07-12 11:02:00 NaN
2016-07-12 11:03:00 NaN
2016-07-12 11:04:00 NaN
2016-07-12 11:05:00 NaN
2016-07-12 11:06:00 NaN
2016-07-12 11:07:00 NaN
2016-07-12 11:08:00 NaN
2016-07-12 11:09:00 NaN
2016-07-12 11:10:00 9.22
2016-07-12 11:11:00 NaN
2016-07-12 11:12:00 9.22
```